# How to extract value from JSON array with javax.json

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have JSON file like this:

```
{
    "mainKey": "Main Value",
    "arrayKey": [{
            "firstSubkey": "First Value",
            "secondSubkey": "Second Value",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am extracting firstSubkey and secondSubkey's value like this:

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(stringReader)) {
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonReader.readObject().getJsonArray("arrayKey");
System.out.println(jsonArray.getJsonObject(0).getString("firstSubkey"));
```

Can I do it cleaner and shorter way?

Comment: use Gson its much cleaner.
Gson tutorial - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/gson_quick_guide.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson, example -

```
String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()); 
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, JsonObject.class);
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("arrayKey");

if (jsonArray != null && jsonArray.size() > 0) {
    String firstValue = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("firstSubkey").getAsString();
    String secondValue = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("secondSubkey").getAsString();

    System.out.println(firstValue);
    System.out.println(secondValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but its like same.